# Jquery and Javascript val() input issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am trying to make a div with the class 'backarea' disappear and at the same time having a different div with the class 'successLog' appear on the screen. Sounds easy I know but the hard part is that I want that to happen only when a certain username and password are entered into 2 different input boxes and the log in button is clicked. The username that has to be entered in is "CodeAcademy" and the password has to be "fun-coding". I don't know what I did wrong but hopefully if you look at my code below you can tell me. I posted all of my code because I don't know what will, and won't be use full. Thank you.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log in box</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="successLog">
<div class="header">
    <ul class="cats">
        <li class="listItems" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="dashboard">Dashboard</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="contactUs">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='dropdownHome'>
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Event Calender</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Bookings</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Picture Gallery</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Login</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownDashboard">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Saved Info</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Friends</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Document</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Profile</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Account</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownContactUs">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Email</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Forum</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Phone-numbers</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Facebook</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div><Br><Br><Br>
    <h1 class="welcomeBack">Hello! Welcome back Code Acedamy</h1>
    <button class="logOut">Log Out</button>
</div>
<div class="backarea">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="userInput" name="userInput"><h2 class="username">Username:</h2></input>
    <input type="password" class="passInput" placeholder="Password"><h2 class="password">Password:</h2></input>
    <button class="login">Log In</button>
    <p class="createacc">Don't have an account? <a href="http://www.example.com/" class="createone">Creat one.</a></p>
    <p class="error">Sorry but that username or password is incorrect.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
.successLog {
    background-color:#8A8A8A;
    height:450px;
    width:700px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
}
.backarea {
    background-color:#6DE3E3;
    width:255px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:9px;
    position:relative;
    top:67px;
    left:230px;
    position:fixed;
}
.userInput {
    padding:5px;
    margin:7px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    left:35px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.userInput:hover {
    border:2px solid #60BF68;
}
.username {
    color:#E60716;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:50px;
    left:75px;
}
.passInput {
    padding:5px;
    margin:7px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:35px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.passInput:hover {
    border:2px solid #60BF68;
}
.password {
    color:#E60716;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:80px;
    left:75px;
}
.login {
    color:white;
    background-color:#E60716;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:60;
    left:71;
    height:40;
    width:80;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.login:hover {
    background-color:#B81414;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.createacc {
    position:relative;
    bottom:73px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    padding:8
}
.createone {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.createone:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.error {
    color:red;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size:10;
    position:relative;
    bottom:93px;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0
}
/*DROP DOWN MENU
/*DEFUALT CLASSES*/
.clicked {
    color:#fff;
}
.invis {
    opacity:0;
}
/*HTML CLASSES*/
.header {
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:10;
}
li {
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    width:100%
}
.cats {
    padding:6px;
    width:100%;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
}
.cats .listItems:hover {
    width:100px;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.cats .listItems:active {
    width:100px;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#318A29;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.listItems {
    padding:70px;
}
.dropdownHome {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:14px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.dropdownDashboard {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:255px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.dropdownContactUs {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:507px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.catLists {
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    right:20;
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
}
.catListItem {
    color:black;
}
.welcomeBack {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color:blue;
    text-align:center;
}
.logOut {
    position:relative;
    top:130px;
    left:312px;
    padding:5px;
    border:none;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.logOut:hover {
    background-color:#B51919;
    border-top:1px solid #F7A3A3;
    border-left:1px solid #F7A3A3;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.login').click(function(){
        var userResult = $('input[name=userInput]').val();
        var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();
        if(userResult === "CodeAcademy" && passResult === "fun-coding") {
           $('.backarea').fadeOut('fast');
           $('.successLog').fadeTo('fast',1);
        };
        else {
        $('.passInput').css('border-color','red');
        $('.userInput').css('border-color','red');
        $('.error').fadeTo('fast',1);
        $('.error').effect( "bounce",{ times: 3 },"slow" );
        };
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownHome').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownHome').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dashboard').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownDashboard').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownDashboard').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactUs').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownContactUs').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownContactUs').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

A lot of the code will not have to do with the problem. A lot of the code is for a drop down menu that will appear when the div does. The javascript is most likely what you need to look at.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the `if` block! Also you could as well use only one block of `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();

<input type="password" class="passInput" placeholder="Password">
```

You are selecting an input with name "passInput" but your password field does not 
have a name.

Either give it a name, or select via the class.

Also your HTML isn't valid. Input elements can't contain HTML and `br`s should  be closed as well.

Comment: Well, `<br>`s are closed to `<br/>` automatically anyways… but you’re definitely right about the `input`s.

Comment: @Xufox True, but browsers will also move HTML outside the input in that case. But either way, I tend to not rely on browsers fixing invalid html as i can't be sure what will happen. Sure, unclosed `br`s may be not a big deal but it's still invalid.

Comment: _“but browsers will also move HTML outside the input in that case”_: yeah… that’s why I said “you’re definitely right about the `input`s”.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, i just meant that browsers will try to "fix" broken HTML whatever it takes. No matter if it's HTML in inputs or open brs. Which in my opinion they should absolutely not. If the HTML is invalid, browsers shouldn't even render it. But i digress.. :)

Comment: "*…and `br`s should be closed…*". Not at all. BR has no end tag and therefore does not need to be closed, see [*HTML 5.1 §4.5.29*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-br-element) and the related code example. The OP is using HTML, so XHTML syntax is not suitable.